# Combining fork() and algorithms

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, optimization, operating-systems

Today in my algorithms class, my professor explained how in divide and conquer algorithms we do things in "parallel" although I felt it was not exactly in parallel. Then I remembered from OS the fork() system call that creates literally another child process and computes in parallel with the parent process. Can we combine these two to give an algorithm that betters the usual Time complexity?

Although  I just realized we have to wait for the child process to complete before the parent, still, some amount of computation can be done in parallel or is there something I am missing?

PS: I am new to this platform so sorry if this isn't the type of questions to be asked here

Comment: In the past, the number of "things" that could be done concurrently was limited by a constant in each given environment. That doesn't change rate of growth comparisons. OTOH, 16 times faster is 16 times faster (beware [Amdahl](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)). And quantum computers are beginning to see use - another can of worms.

Comment: Oh I see if it was for large no of input then yeah we can't create that many processes ig thnx!

Comment: Good question! Under normal circumstances, there is  limit to the number of running proxesses at each point in time (limited to the number of logical processesors). Therefore, this will not have any effect on the asymptotic complexity, even though it might give a certain speedup (if used correctly)

Comment: Welcome @Lakshman.  From a practical point of view, fork is a bit of overkill as it creates a new process. In modern OS’s you can have multiple threads in one process, which is usually more convenient for parallel algorithms. Also, more processes or more threads does not always mean more parallelism. E.g. if you have a one core processor without hyperthreading, the threads (or processes) will just share that core and there will be no speedup. Even on a multicore processor, a multithreaded implementation may end up being slower if the fastest cache is not shared between the cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can we combine these two to give an algorithm that betters the usual Time complexity?

The key to your question is "what do you mean by time complexity?"  Often it is quite clear, and we don't have to state it, but other times we do need to be careful.

Sometimes the thing you are interested in is the complexity class measured in number of operations.  In these cases, forking does not help.  You still have to do the operations.  Other times, you are really-truly interested in the run time of the algorithm with respect to "wallclock" time.  In these cases, you can reduce the run time by *up to* a factor of $n$, where $n$ is the number of processes.

Not all algorithms can be reduced by a full factor of $n$.  In fact, in cryptography, there is a great interest in algorithms that are so mind-numbingly serial that no amount of parallelization can speed them up (such algorithms offer protection against giant clusters of GPUs pounding away at them).  On the other hand, we have the class that can be reduced by $n$, for any $n$ you choose.  These are known as "trivially parallelizable" problems, and we stop talking about how long the algorithm takes and start talking about how large your wallet is.  One doesn't always have infinite computing capacity handy!  Computing resources cost money!

Comment: Nice! I completely disregarded the "computing resources", Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I also enjoy the expression _[embarrassingly parallelizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)_.

Comment: @pipe that's the term I'm more familiar with!

Answer (score 2):

Many divide-and-conquer algorithms are actually implemented sequentially, and the idea of working on each half "in parallel" is more to help with conceptual understanding than an actual implementation practice.

That said: yes, you are quite right, often it is possible to implement these steps concurrently / in parallel.  The details can be tricky, because they require coordination and synchronization between the concurrent threads, consideration of the effect on the memory hierarchy, and there is some performance overhead associated with these issues.  Working through those details requires understanding the processor architecture and memory hierarchy at a low level of detail.  Introductory algorithms courses usually work at a higher level of abstraction, and so do not consider these issues.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely not in the scope of an algorithms class, Thanks for the answer!